# How to check if a drive is connected (mounted)?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

is it possible wit Qt Qprocess to detect if a mounted Loacation(maybe NAS) is connected?
Generally i would check in /proc/mounts if there is an entry, but if i disconnect to the NAS the file doesn't realizes it.
with the df command i can check if a mountpoint is available. But if the connection is disconnected the df process doesn't gives an output. Maybe infinite.

I tried it with

```
QProcess p;
p.start("bash", QStringList() << "-c" <<
      "df -P -T /media/storage/ | grep QIS | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'");
if (p.waitForFinished(2))
{
  qDebug() << "Nothing";
  p.close();
}
```

But nothing happens.

It seems that my program "freezes" when i try to df to a directory which ist'n mounted. Is it possible to cancel the process if there is no answer from the df process after, for example, 2 seconds?

Comment: Are you looking for https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting mounted drives on Linux and Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18600377/detecting-mounted-drives-on-linux-and-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `QProcess`, `QProcess::waitForFinished` takes msec as argument, not sec. Furthermore, it is better to connect to [`QProcess::finished`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#finished) signal instead of blocking the event loop.

That being said, why using `QProcess`, when there is a `QStorageInfo` with a [`mountedVolumes`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstorageinfo.html#mountedVolumes) method:

```
for (const auto &storage : QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes()) {
    if (storage.isValid() && storage.isReady()) {
        if (!storage.isReadOnly()) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank but this doesn't work for me. With QStorageInfo i can print all mounted devices but  there is still no answer wehen i try to list my unmounted device.

Comment: @DaveR, how do you expect to see something, which does not exist?